# Restarting a for-loop with a changed iterator on an exception

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, try-except

I have a block of code which works like for every ID in my Dataframe, it should perform the "TRY" block code and for errors , go to exception, and my data will be changed, and after performing except code,it should again go back to the for loop, but it seems like the Dataframe under the for loop doesn't get updated on the basis of the except code block

```
for ID in data:
  try:
     user= api.get_user(ID)
     engine.execute("insert into sometable values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", str(ID), user.screen_name, user.description)
  except:
     data=pd.read_sql('sqltable',engine)
```

Please help

Giving and another example which seems a constraint of for loop

```
list=[1,2,3]

for x in list:
  print list
  if x==3:
     list=[3,8,9,100,500,600,700]
     print list
```

Despite of updated List the x in list will remain same, what it was earlier i.e 3

Comment: Is that the actual indentation of your code or have you transcribed it badly?

Comment: You need to *commit* after you execute an SQL statement that changes the database. `dbconn.commit()` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention at that, I am so overwhelmed with the problem itself

Comment: @Evert SQLpart is working fine, I am more concerned for the for loop update

Comment: You're also changing the value of your `data` *while* looping over it at the same time. Don't do that! Restart the loop if you change `data` completely.

Comment: @Evert - I want to automate it, that's the problem how to restart the loop with the new data

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Perhaps we can help you with a better understanding

Comment: What is `eachID`? Did you simply mean `ID`? Also, don't catch all exceptions - there might be other errors that will be hidden if you catch everything. Target the specific exception that should cause you to reload the data.

Comment: @Ricardo - So I am trying to get some info for each ID from the Dataframe, and when it throw an error, I read some other table from SQL, so now my table is different under for loop

Comment: Why don't you load all possible tables at first, and then you just iterate over each applying the same logic?

Comment: BTW, check if you are doing what you are supposed to do. From the code you posted here, and my understanding, it is inserting instead of just getting info from the Dataframe. So it might be tricking you too

Comment: So, If you guys will notice despite of a new list/Dataframe- the index number i.e. length of for loop wont change

Comment: I've changed the title of your question: I think this fits better with what you're currently asking, but mostly, I felt it's more generic this way.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the solution to your *actual* problem (since that may solved better differently, but hard to tell), this is one way to re-run a loop with an updated list/data-frame/iterator/whatever:

```
mylist = [-1, 0, 1, 2]
while True:
    print('---:', mylist)
    for x in mylist:
        print(x)
        try:
            5/x
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            # update our list
            mylist = [el+1 for el in mylist]
            break  # shortcut for-loop
    else:
        # for loop completed; break out of while loop
        break
```

which prints

```
---: [-1, 0, 1, 2]
-1
0
---: [0, 1, 2, 3]
0
---: [1, 2, 3, 4]
1
2
3
4
```

I doubt this is the best solution, but how often does one get to use the `else` clause to a `for` statement?